# Deactivate OpenLayers Control

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I have a control that draw line. What I want is that once the line is drawn the control should be deactivated.

```
new GeoExt.Action(Ext.apply({
    text: 'Draw Line',
    control: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
        this.layer,OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        eventListeners: {
            featureadded: this.myFunction,
            scope: this
        }
    })
}, actionDefaults))


myFunction: function(evt) {//Deactivate Control Here }
```

Answer (score 2):

Call this method for deactivate control:

```
control.deactivate();
```